# Google Analytics Content Groupings with Regex

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm attempting to setup [Content Groupings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167) for a website.

My url structure is as follows:

```
http://website.com/news/2014/3/31/MBB_0331140148.aspx?path=mbball
http://website.com/news/2014/3/31/MBB_0331141819.aspx?path=mbball
http://website.com/news/2014/4/11/MBB_0411140500.aspx?path=mbball
http://website.com/news/2014/4/12/FB_0412140313.aspx?path=football
http://website.com/news/2014/4/14/MBB_0414142539.aspx?path=mbball
http://website.com/news/2014/4/15/MBB_0415145757.aspx?path=mbball
http://website.com/news/2014/4/17/FB_0417140744.aspx?path=football
http://website.com/news/2014/4/17/MBB_0417143800.aspx?path=mbball
http://website.com/news/2014/4/2/MBB_0402140734.aspx?path=mbball
```

For the RegEx I used the following code (to match all basketball):

```
/news/201[0-9]/[0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/.*\.aspx\?path=mbball
```

Should My RegEx really be the following to capture all the news groupings?

```
/news/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/.*\?.*path=([^&]+)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`.*` will catch everything, as much as possible. You have included the `?` which makes the star match as few times as possible. However, seeing as you are trying to catch ALL news, Try:

```
/news/.*?path=[^&]+
```

This will catch everything from news/ to the end, including path and as many non-& chars as possible.

Comment: The groups will be set by the path correct? So it'll catch all news links and group them by sport?

EDIT: It seems Google Analytics is grouping my the year (or the first option after the news/ ) How do I adjust to group for the path?

Comment: I have never used content grouping, but from the link you gave it looks like this regex is used to find all the content to be organized, then the regex you provided will group the basketball. Regexs do not group, they only match.

Comment: If you want to catch the whole directory between /news/ and the URI parameters, you could do `/news/(.*?)\?path=.*`